# cygwin and pdftk

Tags: cygwin, pdftk

I have Cygwin install 64-bit version and have installed apt-cyg; using this, I have installed openssh and vim just fine, but I am not able to install pdftk. Does it have some other name? Or is there some other tool I can use to split and merge pdf files in Cygwin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [search on cygwin website](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=pdftk&arch=x86) (and also google). If you try the same search with x86_64 architecture, [there is no such package](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=pdftk&arch=x86_64). This question was [asked](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-09/msg00338.html) many times and [answered](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-09/msg00339.html) also.

Just use 32 bit version, if you want all the packages.

Comment: blitzter47's answer allows pdftk to be used in Cygwin either in 64-bit or 32-bit architectures...

Comment: Note that pdftk has been removed from the Cygwin packages due to a requirement for gcj which was also removed sometime late 2016. See https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-08/msg00656.html

Answer (score 15):

I got PDFtk commands with Cygwin by installing the server version of PDFtk (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) in Windows 7 64bits.

While installing PDFtk Server, make sure to check the box saying to apply PDFtk to the system environment.
Once the installation is done, type "pdftk" in Cygwin and it should give the expected results.

Comment: @blitzer47 I don't know why this is not not the accepted answer. Not only have you shown that it's possible to install pdftk on Cygwin, but the process could not have been more painless. Thank you for your input.

Comment: This has worked flawlessly on my machine and has delivered everything I need. Highly recommended.

Comment: This is a good workaround as it makes the pdftk tool available on the Cygwin command-line. Maybe its not accepted as the answer because it doesn't install a Cygwin package, it installs a windows command-line tool which is accessible in Cygwin (like all other windows command-line tools, e.g. try "dir")

Answer (score 2):

since pdftk is no more supported:
found this package in cygwin to rotate pdfs and more: qpdf
http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/

manual:
http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/files/qpdf-manual.pdf

works with the x64 and x86 version
installed it with the cygwin-installer.